# Could not deduce (TypeClass a0) arising from a use of ‘variable’

Tags: haskell, typeclass, higher-rank-types

I have a type:

```
type DifferentiableFunction n a = (Function n a, List n (Function n a), String)
```

Elsewhere I define:

```
data Something where
  Operator :: Something -> (forall a . Floating a => DifferentiableFunction n a) -> Something
```

Now I try to pattern match:

```
case something of
  (Operator s f) -> let (_, _, l) = f in l
```

I get `Could not deduce (Floating a0) arising from a use of ‘f’`. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Why are you using that universal type? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to limit the type of functions to those working with `Floating` types. My earlier declaration was `data Something a` without a universal type, but I run into other problems. These had to do with wrapping `Something a` into an existential wrapper (it has other parameters besides `a`) and using the `ad` package (the differentiable function type is a bit misleading, I just need a labeled function). My code pretty much works now, except this function that tries to extract the label. I may post another question at a later point about restoring the `a` parameter.

Comment: @chi Long story short: the `ad` package doesn't work with concrete types such as `Double`, it needs these typeclass constraints (actually the universal quantifier) to be able to use its own types that instantiate them.

Comment: The issue here is that your `l` variable must be polytypes and GHC can't infer polytypes. You probably need to use `let l = case f of (_,_,x)->x in ...` and probably need an explicit annotation for `l`. Without seeing the rest of the code, I'd still think that using the `Something a` approach is simpler, though.

Comment: Have you mistyped your pattern-match? `(_, _, l)` is quite different from `(_, _. l)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `let (_, _. l) = f in l` does not specify what type to use for `f`: it could be `DifferentiableFunction n Double` or `DifferentiableFunction n Float` or something else altogether. Because you only use a part which does not depend on `a` (`l` is just a `String`, no matter what `a` is), the compiler is unable to decide what type `f` should have (`a` is ambigious, i.e. the compile does not know what to pick for `a`).

The solution therefore is to give an explicit type signature for f:

```
case something of
  (Operator s f) -> let (_, _, l) = (f :: DifferentiableFunction n Double) in l
```

Or alternatively, lift the `String` out of the forall:

```
type DifferentiableFunction n a = (Function n a, List n (Function n a))
data Something where
  Operator :: Something -> (forall a . Floating a => DifferentiableFunction n a) -> String -> Something -- String is not inside the `forall a.`
```

Now you can get the `String` without needing to pick a specific `a`, because it really is independent of `a`.

Comment: Thanks. If I pick Double and then use the same `something`, somewhere where a `DifferentiableFunction Float` is required, could that create problems?

Comment: @denormal no that won't cause problems, because the `f` binding is polymorphic due to the forall, so it can be used at different types in different places.